# Custom DCG Operators

Tags: prolog, dcg, meta-predicate

Suppose I want to write a custom operator for composing DCG rules in a way that would otherwise be repetitive.

For example, suppose I had I a DCG, `ws` such that:

```
ws --> [].
ws --> " ", ws.
```

to match zero or more spaces. Obviously, if I want optional whitespace between each token in my grammar, it's obnoxious to have to put `, ws` everywhere.

I could define a new operator to replace `,/2`.

```
:- op(1000, xfy, [ -- ]).
:- meta_predicate --(*,*,?,?).
--(L,R) --> ({callable(L)} -> call(L); L), ws, ({callable(R)} -> call(R); R).
```

This joines the left and right hand of `--/2` via the optional whitespace rule. This mostly works fine, however certain things trip it up:

```
rule --> "foo" -- ("bar"; "quux").
```

If I try and execute this rule, I get an error saying that `;/4` is not defined. I have a vague idea of the problem here, but basically the question is: is there a way to define new operators for DCGs that work with the same generality as `,/2`?

Comment: Please rather use `2` in place of `*`.  That is: `:- meta_predicate --(2,2,?,?)`.

Comment: Please do not expect to get answers, if you are deleting your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60712682/772868).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, this is possible.

Currently, the main problem is:

```
?- callable("foo").
true.
```

So, I suggest this simpler definition:

```
--(L, R) --> L, ws, R.
```

In addition, I suggest:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).
```

Sample query:

```
?- phrase(rule, Ls).
Ls = [f, o, o, b, a, r] ;
Ls = [f, o, o, q, u, u, x] ;
Ls = [f, o, o, ' ', b, a, r] ;
Ls = [f, o, o, ' ', q, u, u, x] ;
Ls = [f, o, o, ' ', ' ', b, a, r] .
```

As another example, let us use this rule instead:

```
rule --> "foo" -- ("bar" | "quux") -- "test".
```

Now we get for example:

```
?- length(Ls, _), phrase(rule, Ls).
Ls = [f, o, o, b, a, r, t, e, s, t] ;
Ls = [f, o, o, b, a, r, ' ', t, e, s, t] ;
Ls = [f, o, o, q, u, u, x, t, e, s, t] ;
Ls = [f, o, o, ' ', b, a, r, t, e, s, t] ;
Ls = [f, o, o, b, a, r, ' ', ' ', t, e, s, t] ;
Ls = [f, o, o, q, u, u, x, ' ', t, e, s, t] ;
Ls = [f, o, o, ' ', b, a, r, ' ', t, e, s, t] ;
Ls = [f, o, o, ' ', q, u, u, x, t, e, s, t] ;
Ls = [f, o, o, ' ', ' ', b, a, r, t, e, s, t] ;
Ls = [f, o, o, b, a, r, ' ', ' ', ' ', t, e, s, t] .
```

Note how **iterative deepening** is used for fair enumeration.